# updating default value at run time and making calculation with the new value in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity

So i have three activities. One is used to accept inputs from the user and a **Next button**  to move to the second activity if all the input are filled.

And the second activity can be used to accept and update some already defined values in the the second class which is used to perform the calculation, a **Save** button to save the new value and **Finish button**  to perform calculation and display the result in the last activity.

How do i update the second activity/class each time i decide to use a new set of values when i click the **Save button** after input?

FIRST ACTIVITY

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/first_number"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter first Number"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/second_number"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter second Number"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/third_number"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter second Number"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/curved_button"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="19dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add_button_image"
    android:text="@string/Next"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:typeface="serif"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


SECOND ACTIVITY
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/contingencyFee"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@color/pageColor"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:hint="@string/contingency"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/projectManagement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@color/pageColor"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:hint="@string/projectFee"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/externalWorks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@color/pageColor"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:hint="@string/externalWorks"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:onClick="saveButton"
    android:background="@drawable/save_button"
    android:text="@string/inputVariableSaveButton"          
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"           
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView16"          
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/proceedBtn"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.464"                 
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.483" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/proceed_button"
    android:layout_width="116dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:onClick="proceed"
    android:text="@string/defaultVariable"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView16"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

FIRST CLASS

btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        public void onClick(View v){
            try{

// **** VALUES FROM THE FIRST ACTIVITY

                double first_number = 
Double.valueOf(first_number.getText().toString());
                double firstNumberTotal = first_number* /* 
(250*70000)*/  17500000;

                double second_number = 
Double.valueOf(second_number.getText().toString());
                double secondNumberTotal = second_number * /* 
(214*70000)*/ 14980000;

                double third_number = 
Double.valueOf(third_number.getText().toString());
                double thirdNumberTotal = third_number * /* 
(140*70000)*/ 9800000;

            }catch (Exception ex){
                return;
            }
        }
    });


 SECOND CLASS
 save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        public void onClick(View v){
            try{

                // VALUES FROM SECOND ACTIVITY
        double contingencyFee = 
        Double.valueOf(contingencyFeet.getText().toString());
                double contingencyTotal = contingencyFee * 
        1.015; /*UPDATE THIS WITH NEW VALUE*/


      double projectManagement = 
      Double.valueOf(projectManagement.getText().toString());
      double totalProjectCost = projectManagemen * 
      1.2; /*UPDATE THIS WITH NEW VALUE*/

      double externalWorks = 
      Double.valueOf(externalWorks.getText().toString());
                double externalWorksCost = externalWorks * 
      1.15; /*UPDATE THIS WITH NEW VALUE*/

            }catch (Exception ex){
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisrt Activity in button click

```
intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("firstno", String.valueOf(firstnumber));
                    intent.putExtra("secondno", String.valueOf(secondnumber));
                    intent.putExtra("thirdno", String.valueOf(thirdnumber));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity on load

```
String firstNo, SecondNo, ThirdNo;
 firstNo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firstno");
 SecondNo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("secondno");
 ThirdNo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("thirdno");
```

Edited Content

```
Double firstNo, SecondNo, ThirdNo;
firstNo = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("firstno"));
SecondNo = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("secondno"));
ThirdNo = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("thirdno"));

textView.setText(String.valueOf(firstNo + SecondNo + ThirdNo));
```

Comment: This worked till i get to the setText(result); and it cannot display the calculated result or even the double value gotten from the first Intent. Its saying "cannot resolve method 'setText(double)'". please any help?

Comment: You'll need to cast Double to String, using String value = Double.toString(0.00111); Then set the string "value" in your setText(value);.

Comment: yeah, i have seen it. It worked, i later used this >> NumberFormat answer = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
            
            display.setText(answer.format(total)); Thank you very much for you quick response, i am grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data from one activity to another by adding it to the intent with which you call the next activity. The [Intent class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) has features to help you send a small amount of information via itself; called putExtra() and getExtra(). More about them [here](https://zocada.com/using-intents-extras-pass-data-activities-android-beginners-guide).

You will need to add those variable data through intent.putExtra and fetch them back in your other activity onCreate by using getExtras.

Activity 1 >> Intent call to Activity 2 + Data >> Activity 2

Then in your finish or calculate button's onClick listener in Activity 2, read data with intent.getExtras and perform the calculation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much. The link you recommended is very useful too

Comment: @Jblaq If it's helped you. Kindly upvote my answer.